# How to pass command line argument or environment variable to frisby scripts from batch script using jest

Tags: batch-file, cmd, jasmine, jestjs, frisby.js

it's doesn't take argument when running in cmd. Basically, it takes the argument as a parameter and searches that argument throughout the file and runs all the files if anything matches to that argument, it's not limited to the particular one.

like files are

**1.login_account_spec.js**

**code:**

```
    var frisby = require("frisby");
    const Joi = frisby.Joi;

   console.log(process.argv)

    /**
    * Commandline parameter includes
    */
    /*  
    var name = process.env['name'];
    var password = process.env['password'];
    var dateTime = record.getDateTime();

    frisby.globalSetup({
        request: { 
            headers : { 
                    "accept": "application/json", 
                    "content-type" : "application/json", 
            }
        }
    });

    it("Test login_account" + dateTime, function (done){
        frisby.get(url)
        .expect("status", 200)
        .expect("header", "content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
        .expect("jsonTypes", "data", {
            "message" : Joi.string(),
            })
        .then(function(res) {
            var body = res.body;
            body = JSON.parse(body);
            expect(body.data.message).toBeDefined();

        })
        .then(function(res) {
            record.createLogFile("login_account" + dateTime, null, res);
        })
        .done(done);
    });
```

**2.get_device_details_spec.js**

**code:**

```
 var frisby = require("frisby");
 const Joi = frisby.Joi;

    console.log(process.argv)


    frisby.globalSetup({
        request: { 
            headers : { 
                "Accept": "application/json", 
                "content-type" : "application/json" 
            }
        }
    });

    it("Test get_device_details" + dateTime, function(done){
        frisby.get(url)
        .expect("status", 200)
        .expect("header", "content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8")
        .expect("jsonTypes", "data", {
            "description": Joi.string(),
        })
            .then(function(res) {
                var body = res.body;
                body = JSON.parse(body);
                expect(body.data.description).toBeDefined();
            })  
        .after(function(res) {
            record.createLogFile("get_device_details" + dateTime, err, res);
        })
        .done(done);
});
```

**Unit_test.bat** that contain scripts(here only two)

```
@echo off
set URL=%1
set NAME=%2
set PASSWORD=%3

set /a var2=1
set /a var=0
set /a varx=0
IF /I "%ITERATION%" NEQ "0" (
    SET var2=%ITERATION%
    SET /a ITERATION=1
)

for /L %%n in (1,%ITERATION%,%var2%) do @(

    jest login_account_spec.js %URL% %NAME% %PASSWORD% 

    REM jest get_device_details_spec.js %URL%  %NAME% %PASSWORD% 

)
```

**In CMD:**

Unit_Test.bat 192.168.1.17:XXXX test1 123

then it gave the result of both these files and these js files are related to Frisby.

so I wants to run only(login_account_spec.js) that file with arguments that i passed in cmd . But, it gave result of both the scripts that, i don't want and it also not taking the arguments that i passed.

Comment: Take your time to [edit] the question to make it easier to read and understand. Select the lines of code and use the `{}` button in the question editor's toolbar to nicely format them. Check how the question looks like in the preview under the editor before pressing the `Save` button. Add the tags related to the question content (f.e., the title says about Windows Command Prompt and `.bat` files but the corresponding tags are missing). This way you improve your chances to get an answer.

Comment: does `counter1.bat` set/change any of the variables `%URL% %HTTPMODE% %USERNAME% %PASSWORD% %ENCRYPTION% %ITERATION% %COMPANYID%
`?

Comment: (Note: `%USERNAME%` is already a system variable. It's recommended to leave them alone until you really have a reason to change them; better give it another name, like `%USER%` or `%NAME%` )

Comment: No, counter1.bat not uses any of the batch variable %URL% %HTTPMODE% %USERNAME% %PASSWORD% %ENCRYPTION% %ITERATION% %COMPANYID%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**.bat file**

```
@echo off
set URL=%1
set HTTPMODE=%2
set USERNAME=%3
set PASSWORD=%4
set ENCRYPTION=%5
set ITERATION=%6
set COMPANYID=%7

REM call current_time.bat   
        REM set config={"httpMode": "%HTTPMODE%","url": "%URL%","encryption": "%ENCRYPTION%","username": "%USERNAME%@gmail.com","password": "%PASSWORD%","companyId": "%COMPANYID%","role": "Owner"}
```

**In .js file:**

```
var objConfig = JSON.parse(process.env.config);

var username = objConfig.username;
var encryption = objConfig.encryption;
```

And in last run on cmd:
xx.bat username password ...

hope it helps to other